# Jquery pagination with first,next and previous,last option

Tags: jquery, pagination

I have searched google for pagination, I found some of pagination.But none of them meet my requirement. I need something like

> << < 1 2 3 >> >

of course we can have like

> First Next 1 2 3 Previous Last

I haven't yet found anything by searching on google. Kindly provide an example link for above requirement.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm this is it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)

Its fulfills your requirement of pagination as well as it gives other facilities such as search and sort and the code is also highly editable....

Comment: Thank you ...very helpful....
But here,depending on <tr>,pagination is generating. Can we use this pagination based on <div> ?

Comment: okay Mr.SM. One more question
But here,depending on <tr>,pagination is generating. Can we use this pagination based on <div> ?

Comment: what do you want to paginate? since DataTables is for displaying data in table structure it is for table pagination only.

Comment: okay. I want to display the some number of images inside DIV with height 550px ,width 200px in page display like 3 rows with 3 images/row,so totally we will get 9 images per page. Here i need pagination(like i said already)if i have more than 9 images per page.