# Need Jquery Pagination with first,previous,next,last buttons

Tags: jquery, pagination

I need Jquery pagination with first,previous,next,last buttons (arrow marks).

The pagination form is ,

<< < 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10 > >>

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to achieve that using jQuery, you'd want to use a server-side solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried to make it and failed? Do you have HTML for it? What data are you showing and where is it coming from? Does jQuery relate to the data? How should the link url look like?

Comment: A possible duplicate of [Jquery pagination with first,next and previous,last option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561772/jquery-pagination-with-first-next-and-previous-last-option/5561804#5561804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins can usually solve these types of problems. Your question is quite vague so I'm not sure what your requirements are however, a quick search on jQuery's site for pagination plugins came up with these. [pagination|jQuery Plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/pagination)

Comment: There's always [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) too but since the OP is too lazy to explain what he's tried (if anything), I doubt this is going anywhere

Comment: yeah..after 2 answers he adds a comment and says he wants a div structure...you're right this is not going anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to have a look at [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)

For more help look at the answer I posted for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561772/jquery-pagination-with-first-next-and-previous-last-option/5561804#5561804)

Comment: Put those DIVs inside the rows...I think that would work fine apart from pagination it allows sorting and searching as well...but still if you want to go with DIV structure then this not useful...